# Property of class as a class and access parent properties

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

Quite tricky to describe what I am asking here, so I will just use a hypothetical example:

```js
import { Address } from "./Address";

export class Customer {
  public firstName: string;
  public address: Address;

  public constructor(firstName: string, city: string) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.address = new Address(city);
  }

}
```

And

```js
export class Address {
  public city: string;

  public constructor(city: string) {
    this.city = city;
    // Can I access the Customer.firstName from here?
  }

}
```

As per my comment in the `Address` class above, is it possible to access the properties of the class that initiated this `address` property (without sending it in as a arg of course)? In this case, the `Customer` instance.

Hope that makes sense?

Comment: That would only be possible if you passed the customer instance (or just their name) into the `Address` constructor. It cannot "magically" work because the same `Address` instance could be associated with multiple customers. But that also shows that maybe the name shouldn't be part of the address.

Comment: That would be a circular dependency which should be avoided. Why would you want to access a Customer from an adress?

Comment: Again, this was a completely hypothetical example, and not real world. I just grabbed Customer and Address as my first example. I just used it to ask if it was possible. What I'm working on right now, likely will never have this issue.. but I wanted to know if it is poss in case I do want access to something outside

Comment: Ah, I conveniently glanced over that. *"I do want access to something outside"* No, that's not possible as such but their might be a solution for your specific situation, should you encounter it.